# What does this sentence mean especially the part in bold? (is consistant with)

Tags: meaning-in-context, interpretation

**The use** **of identifiable symbols and pictograms** on the early tablets **is consistent with administrators needing a lexicon** that was mutually intelligible by literate and nonliterate parties.

What does this sentence mean especially the part in bold?

Comment: can you explain what the problem is here.  The level of vocabulary is quite high, but all these words are in the dictionary.

Comment: an exceprt from "a research paper" which I don't have

Comment: Images used on early tablets needed to understood both by people who could read and those who could not. Administrators appeared to to select images accordingly.